# Получение длительности видео, Android

Tags: java, android, видео

Есть mp4 файл, как я могу получить длительность видеозаписи?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Получить длительность видео можно как:

```
MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, Uri.parse(uriOfFile));
int duration = mp.getDuration();
```

<sub>[Источник](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3936396/how-to-get-duration-of-a-video-file).</sub>